# Why SQL server view is not good to work with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i read these articles

http://a4academics.com/interview-questions/52-dot-net-interview-questions/973-entity-framework?showall=&start=2

they said

> Below are the points we can consider increasing the performance –
>
> Disable the Change Tracking if it’s not required.
>
> Use the compiled
>   query whenever required.
>
> Avoid using Views
>
> Fetch the required data
>   from database.

1) what they try to mean avoid using views.

we can have views in db and that we can refer by edmx. so what would be the problem if we call view by EF instead of table ?

i like to know what happen when we call view by EF.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps they are speaking about insert/updates on a view, and not about select on a view (see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351942/is-it-bad-practice-to-insert-and-update-through-database-views and the upvoted comment on the response)

Comment: This seems pretty dated, for example "Our tests indicate that using CompiledQuery can bring a benefit of 7% over autocompiled LINQ queries"..."Generally speaking, the cost of writing and maintaining CompiledQuery objects in EF 5.0 may not be worth the trouble when compared to the benefits" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853

Comment: my intention is not insert or update data by view rather just select....so should i use view?

Comment: They may consider views to impact performance in EF because EF wants an entity with a primary key. Your  view may not have a column that is unique so EF will  generate a View in the EDMX and  all the columns will be the entity key. Also, if you have a view calling a view, etc, performance slows dramatically. A view in a loop will cause  slowdowns because the view is repopulated each time it is called in the loop.

Comment: @L0uis it isn't a fair statement to make ONLY in the context of EF.  This would be true for any query via any mechanism.

Comment: I am making the statement in the context of EF because that is what the question is about. Who said its only in the context of EF?

Answer (score 1):

Really the *only* problem with views is that they don't always contain unique candidate primary keys.

A view can contain rows like

```
ID1 ID2 SomeColumn
==================
  1   4          A
  1   5          A
  1   5          B
```

where both `ID` columns originate from primary key table columns.

When imported into an EDMX, EF will infer a primary key and may conclude that `{ ID1, ID2 }` is a good candidate. As you see, it isn't. In this case it should also include `SomeColumn`, but in other cases there may not even be a unique combination of view fields!

In Entity Framework 6 and earlier that caused EF to materialize identical entities like

```
  1 4 A
  1 5 A
  1 5 A (!)
```

As you see, the third row is duplicated.

This has caused great confusion among developers and lots of Stack Overflow questions. It's just that when the view contains a proper unique candidate key, which is mapped as primary key in the EF model, it's perfectly OK to use views for *read-only* data in EF queries.

This confusing issue won't be fixed in EF6 any more, but Entity Framework core (as of v2.1) has added support for reading unidentifiable view data. A view can be read into any type and reading the view will simply return the view rows without duplications caused by non-unique keys: there *are* no keys.

The type can be added to the model by:

```
modelBuilder.Query<MyViewDto>().ToView("MyView");
```

...and used in a LINQ query like so:

```
db.Query<MyViewDto>().Where(x => x.ID1 == 1)
```

This will be translated into a SQL query with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#query-types